# Passport-JWT token passed, user found, but isAuthenticated returns false

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, passport.js, passport-jwt

Have been dealing with a tough one that I can't figure out even after diving in to the Passport source code for a couple hours.

I'm using a passport.js setup with jwt and a strange thing is occuring in that my authentication on my routes (on my node server, authenticated with passport.authenticate wrapping the routes) work perfectly - but a call to isAuthenticated fails despite being logged in and the jwt strategy being called and successfully returning done(null,user) every time.

Code included below:

app.js

```
let strategy2 = new JwtStrategy(jwtOptions, function(jwt_payload, done) {

  Auth.findById(jwt_payload.id).then(user=>{
  if (user) {

    done(null, user);
  } else {
    done(null, false);
  }
  });

});
// use the strategy
passport.use(strategy2);
```

relevant code in auth.controller.js is:

```
exports.logged_in = function(req,res){

        res.send(req.isAuthenticated() ? req.user :'0');
    }

exports.auth_post = async (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate(['local','jwt'], {session: false}, (err, user, info) => {
        if (err || !user) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                message: 'Something is not right',
                user   : user
            });
        }
        else{
       req.login(user, {session: false}, (err) => {
           if (err) {
               res.send(err);
           }
           // generate a signed json web token with the contents of user object and return it in the response
           // the only personalized value that goes into our token
            let payload = { id: user.id };
            let token = jwt.sign(payload, 'secret');
            res.json({ msg: 'ok', token: token });
            } 
    );}
    })(req, res);
};
```

And diving into passport.js, the call to the isAuthenticated method, which looks like this:

```
req.isAuthenticated = function() {
  var property = 'user';
  if (this._passport && this._passport.instance) {

    property = this._passport.instance._userProperty || 'user';

    return (this[property]) ? true : false;
  }
```

returns null for this[property] despite property being 'user'.

So far I've tried many related answers, including messing with my .findOne function to grab the user, and modifying the order of my middleware setup (this is related to session typically, which I'm not using with JWT).

Thanks for any help,

Comment: `this[property]` is never assigned, you assign to a local variable named `property` right?

Comment: @MatJ this[property] is expected to be automatically set by passport, to my understanding.